# Error in Windowing a Time Series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to window a time series to plot a particular week of data. However I receive the following error message

```
Error in .window.timeSeries(x, start, end, ...) : 
  .window.timeSeries is for time series and not for signal series.
In addition: There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(timeSeries)
TimeDate <- c("15-Jun-04/09","15-Jun-04/19","16-Jun-04/05")
Northwest <- c("898", "893", "948")
NorthwestSeries <- timeSeries(Northwest, TimeDate, format="%Y/%m/%d/%H")
week.N <- series(window(NorthwestSeries, 
                 start=timeDate("15-Jun-04-09",format="%d-%b-%y-%H"),             
                 end=timeDate("16-Jun-04-05",format="%d-%b-%y-%H")))
```

How can I fix this!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to make your questino reproducible

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I presume that Northwest2010 is NorthwestSeries?

Comment: Yes sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time and date format is not right, and I've changed those format to:

```
NorthwestSeries <- timeSeries(Northwest, TimeDate, format="%y-%b-%d/%H")
week.N <- series(window(NorthwestSeries, 
                 start=timeDate("15-Jun-04-09",format="%y-%b-%d/%H"),             
                 end=timeDate("16-Jun-04-05",format="%y-%b-%d/%H")))
```

`y` - for year with 2 digits

`b` - abbreviation of month name

`H` - hour in 24Hours format

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find documentation on the format parameter? (The R documentation is not very extensive in the timeSeries package for the window function)

Comment: it's simple as `?strptime`.